# Unable to Unmarshall a xml in java using JAXB without using any annotation- No error but Unmarshalling is incorrect

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am trying to Convert XML content into a Java Object using JAXB **without using any annotation**. My XML file (CustomerDtl.xml) structure is mentioned below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<basePojo>
<customerId>C001</customerId>
<customerList>
    <Customer>
        <name>Ram</name>
        <phoneNo>123445</phoneNo>
    </Customer>

    <Customer>
        <name>Tom</name>
        <phoneNo>2332322</phoneNo>
    </Customer>
</customerList>
</basePojo>
```

and my pojos are

***BasePojo.java***

```
package pojo;

import java.util.List;

import pojo.Customer;

public class BasePojo {

    List<Customer> customerList;
    String customerId;

    public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
        return customerList;
    }

    public void setCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList) {
        this.customerList = customerList;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

}
```

***Customer.java***

```
package pojo;

public class Customer {

    private String name;

    private String phoneNo;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhoneNo() {
    return phoneNo;
}

public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
    this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
}

}
```

Below mentioned piece of code I have written to Convert XML content into a Java Object

```
    try {

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(BasePojo.class);
        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("CustomerDtl.xml");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<BasePojo> jaxbElementObject = unmarshaller.unmarshal(
                xml, BasePojo.class);
        BasePojo bPojo = jaxbElementObject.getValue();

        System.out.println("id="+bPojo.getCustomerId());
        System.out.println("list size="+bPojo.getCustomerList().size());

        Iterator iterator = bPojo.getCustomerList().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Customer studentDetails = (Customer) iterator.next();
            System.out.println("Print Name:" + studentDetails.getName());
        }

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception:" + e);
    }
```

And the out put of this code is

```
id=C001
list size=1
list size=[pojo.Customer@3e3abc88]
Print Customer Name:null
```

After executing this program it's prints the correct customerId, but it prints the wrong customer list size **1**. Although the list size is 1, and the list contains Customer object but when I iterate through the list and try to get different property value of Customer, I am getting null.

Can any one explain me what I need to correct? Using annotation I tried and it is working as expected. Is it not possible without annotation?

Comment: You may try using for(final Customer customer : pBojo.getCustomerList()) { ...   instead of your while loop.  I wonder if your generic Iterator is causing the issue.  If you're going to use an iterator, it should at least be Iterator<Customer> iterator = ... (An IDE like Eclipse would give you a warning in your current code)

Comment: lets's skip the iteration part. Why the list size is 1, any idea?

Comment: Good question.  What annotation(s) exactly were you using that was making it work?

Comment: '@XmlRootElement' in class level,'@XmlElement' in setter methods

Comment: If you say you do not want any annotation, what does that mean? You don't want @XmlElement annotation as well? It can be achieved without any annotation. Because to get the "Customer" with capital C, you need at least @XMLElement(name="Customer"). Rest everything can be done without wrapper annotation.. Let me know if that is what your requirement is

Comment: I am working in an existing project and the pojo classes of this project contains only properties and getter setter methods. I don't want to touch them. But for a different purpose I need to populate pojos values from xml using unmarshiling. That's why I am not going to use `@XmlElement`, `@XmlElement` annotation to annotate my pojos. Hence no annotation.

Comment: Wow. So you can't change pojo but you can change XML that may be coming from a different server. That was quite illogical. Nevertheless ... Your problem, your solution :)

Comment: I have a restriction on pojo side. I told earlier that all the pojos are part of an existing project and I don't want to touch them and that's why I go with XML structure change. And please don't take it personally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the xml you don't have to specify the class name (`Customer`) as the child of your list (`customerList`), just use the list name directly for every element.

So, change the xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<basePojo>
<customerId>C001</customerId>

<customerList>
    <name>Ram</name>
    <phoneNo>123445</phoneNo>
</customerList>

<customerList>
    <name>Tom</name>
    <phoneNo>2332322</phoneNo>
</customerList>

</basePojo>
```

Comment: Hi, I am also facing some issues during the `XmlStreamReader` and `JAXB Unmarshalling`. If you get a chance can you please have a look at this question and provide your suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67667516/jaxb-moxy-unmarshalling-for-large-file-fails-for-some-events

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
    

        try {
            XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
            StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("CustomerDtl.xml");
            XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);
            while(xsr.hasNext()) {
                if(xsr.isStartElement() && "Customer".equals(xsr.getLocalName())) {
                    break;
                }
                xsr.next();
             }
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            Customer customer = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, Customer.class).getValue();
            System.out.println(customer.getName());

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception:" + e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go if you do not want any annotation (with exact xml that you shared).

1) Wrap your list to a wrapper class (to handle customerList)

2) Now as I asked in Comment, if you have "Customer" element, then default "xml" name recognized will be with small c. If you don't want to annotate even that, then handle it while reading it.

After having said so here is an working sample (with runnable main) modifying your BasePojo

```
package pojo;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class BasePojo {

    String customerId;
    CustomerList customerList;

    public CustomerList getCustomerList() {
        return customerList;
    }

    public void setCustomerList(CustomerList customerListObject) {
        this.customerList = customerListObject;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String customerData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n"
                    + "<basePojo>\n"
                    + "<customerId>C001</customerId>\n"
                    + "<customerList>\n"
                    + "    <Customer>\n"
                    + "        <name>Ram</name>\n"
                    + "        <phoneNo>123445</phoneNo>\n"
                    + "    </Customer>\n"
                    + "\n"
                    + "    <Customer>\n"
                    + "        <name>Tom</name>\n"
                    + "        <phoneNo>2332322</phoneNo>\n"
                    + "    </Customer>\n"
                    + "</customerList>\n"
                    + "</basePojo>";
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(BasePojo.class);
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(customerData);
            StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(reader);
            XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
            XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(customerData.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            xsr = new StreamReaderDelegate(xsr) {
                @Override
                public String getLocalName() {
                    String localName = super.getLocalName();

                    if ("Customer".equals(localName)) {
                        return "customer";
                    }
                    return localName;
                }

            };

            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            JAXBElement<BasePojo> jaxbElementObject = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, BasePojo.class);
            BasePojo bPojo = jaxbElementObject.getValue();

            System.out.println("id=" + bPojo.getCustomerId());
            System.out.println("list size=" + bPojo.getCustomerList().getCustomer().size());

            Iterator iterator = bPojo.getCustomerList().getCustomer().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Customer studentDetails = (Customer) iterator.next();
                System.out.println("Print Name:" + studentDetails.getName());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception:" + e);
        }

    }
}

class CustomerList {

    private List<Customer> customer;

    public List<Customer> getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(List<Customer> customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

}
```

Comment: In my program xml file is in the drive and the program read it as a file.

Comment: it's working, but they way you have implemented it, bit complex in my opinion. But thanks for your help and effort.

Comment: Isn't it simple to change code to read from file ( where I am using string). I used string for completeness of example. And I don't see how much more complex it is from the code you shared. It just had a single wrapper class extra. Rest is same as your pojo. Unmarshalling code will also be same except for one override. Nevertheless, please share your simple code that follows all your restriction of _no annotations_ , no XML change etc